# Evaluate this Kronecker Delta multiplication

Tags: kronecker-delta

I need to evaluate this multiplication of kronecker deltas

$$\delta_{ij}\delta_{km}\delta_{jk}\delta_{im}$$

seems to be a very simple exercise, but my question is: Can I change the order of the deltas to reduce the terms?
I mean to use this property: $$\sum_{k} \delta_{ik}\delta_{kj} = \delta_{ij}.$$

thanks

Comment: If you are using the convention that repeated indices are to be summed over, you should state that explicitly.

Comment: @WillOrrick you mean i should do this  $$\sum_{i = 1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3 \sum_{m = 1}^3  \delta_{ij} \delta_{km}\delta_{jk}\delta_{im}

$$

Comment: Not necessarily. You can just state the convention in words.

Comment: To answer your question: yes. Multiplication of delta functions is commutative.

Comment: @Andrei so, this is correct? $$\delta_{ij}\delta_{km}\delta_{jk}\delta_{im}=\delta_{mj}\delta_{jm}=\delta_{jj} = 3$$

Comment: Yes, if the dimensionality of the space is 3.

Comment: @Andrei thx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder the deltas. This follows from basic properties of arithmetic. Changing the order of factors in a product is allowed because of commutativity of multiplication. With the summation convention in place, however, you have to think a bit harder about why certain rearrangements are allowed, since what looks like a product is actually a sum of products. Consider an arbitrary function $f$ that takes two elements of $\{1,2\}$ as arguments, and consider the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2f_{ij}.
$$
If you adopt the sensible convention that the inner sum is to be performed first, this represents $f_{11}+f_{12}+f_{21}+f_{22}$, which can be thought of as the row-first summation of the array elements in
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
f_{11} & f_{12}\\
f_{21} & f_{22}.
\end{array}
$$
If you change the order of the summations,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^2\sum_{i=1}^2f_{ij}.
$$
you get $f_{11}+f_{21}+f_{12}+f_{22}$, which is equal to the previous expression because of commutativity of addition. This is like doing a column-first summation of the array above.

Now consider the double summation
$$
\sum_{j=1}^2\sum_{k=1}^2f_{ij}f_{jk}f_{k\ell}.
$$
The distributive law allows use to write this as
$$
\sum_{j=1}^2f_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^2f_{jk}f_{k\ell}.
$$
This is because, for fixed $i$, $j$, and $\ell$, every term in the inner sum over $k$ has the factor $f_{ij}$, which may therefore be pulled out, e.g. (with $i=j=1$, $\ell=2$) we have
$$
f_{11}f_{11}f_{12}+f_{11}f_{12}f_{22}=f_{11}(f_{11}f_{12}+f_{12}f_{22}).
$$
Now if $f$ were the delta function, we could then simplify the inner sum to $\delta_{12}$.

Thinking in these terms should allow you to decide for yourself when an rearrangement is allowed.